# How to execute a c# exe from a c++ program

Tags: c++, c

I have made a small program in c# called Registry.exe.

Now i my c++ program i want to call this Registry.exe is there a way to do it.

User cannot give any inputs the call is to be based on conditions

Comment: @hardyz009 You seriously should revise the way you're asking questions and reflect how SO works. What did you try so far? Did you try anything at all (Google for instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use ShellExecute(), ShellExecuteEx() or CreateProcess()...

ie.

```
HINSTANCE hInst = ShellExecute(0, "open", "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe",  "c:\\example.txt", 0, SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cann simply use

system("Registry.exe");

Comment: my file name is GUI for Registry.exe including the space .
I dont knw where to paste the reigstry to i pasted in along with the exe of the c++ program .Now whne i run system(GUI for Registry.exe) the output screen say GUI is not a recognised command

Comment: it works with system also but you need to paste your exe in windows folder

Comment: You can give the whole path in system();

Answer (score 0):

The language an executable is written in is irrelevant, the OS merely sees an executable.

You can invoke any command that would be valid from the command line with the `system()` call declared in `<cstdlib>`.  Any more flexible or controllable means of launching a separate process is OS specific, and you will need to consult your OS documentation.  In Win32, you have the choice of:

- [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and related functions),
- [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or its `..Ex` variant,
- the [`_spawn` family of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx),
- or the [`_exec` family of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w.aspx).